# Prediction using binary spatial autocorrelation

Tags: predictive-models, autocorrelation, spatial

I want to probabilistically infer the binary state of nearby pixels from some samples. Example:
? ? ? ? ?
? ? 1 ? ?
0 ? ? 1 ?
? ? ? 1 ?
? ? ? ? ?
I have a few examples to measure the spatial autocorrelation in this type of data; the spatial structure of new images should be similar (it represents lakes and rivers).
[image: example map]
How can I use e.g. **Moran's I** to infer the probability of the "?" pixels in the example? Does Moran's I even provide useful information about pixels more than 1 unit apart from the sample? Can I realistically get good probabilistic expectations for points a few units away from the nearest sample based on auto-correlation or is it the wrong tool for this job?

Comment: Possible direction: [Image restoration technique using Kriging](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1306/1306.0139.pdf) with combination with [indicator kriging](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geostatistical-analyst/understanding-indicator-kriging.htm)

Comment: I have some doubts about the viability of this algorithm with few known pixels that are spread out relatively far, but I will look into it. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: I concur with Dahn Jahn (above). This is an interpolation problem and it sounds like indicator kriging would be your best bet.